# Setting same extent for multiple rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, extents

I am looking for a tool or plugin for QGIS that would allow me to shift several rasters to one, very same coordinates. Extent of them has to be identical. These rasters all have the same coordinate system and were clipped with the same layer, and they still tiny differ in coordinate values, making it impossible for me to use them for further analysis in IDRISI. I can also do it in QGIS (probably even better). I sometimes need to change x1, and leave x2 without any changes, so Shift tool is not good because it moves them both.

Below I provide a screenshot of raster properties:

[image]

4th property is "Zasięg" (English: Extent). I have 8 raster layers which have 4 different extents:

CLC1990:

606194,0999999999767169,431662,1996999999973923 : 652002,5999999999767169,475750,2996999999741092

CLC2006:

606194,0999999999767169,431662,1996999999973923 : 652002,5999999999767169,475750,2996999999741092

CLC2018:

606194,0999999999767169,431662,1996999999973923 : 652002,5999999999767169,475750,2996999999741092

NMT 606158,3214000000152737,431681,3973000000114553 : 651958,3214000000152737,475781,3973000000114553

P_Stream 606189,0999999999767169,431667,2000000000116415 : 651999,0999999999767169,475757,2000000000116415

Stream 606189,0999999999767169,431667,2000000000116415 : 651999,0999999999767169,475757,2000000000116415

PRoads 606194,0999999999767169,431660,2999999999883585 : 652004,0999999999767169,475750,2999999999883585

Roads 606194,0999999999767169,431660,2999999999883585 : 652004,0999999999767169,475750,2999999999883585

I have to make the extents identical. So I basically need only 1 value of extent which is the same for every layer. Layers have the same size (width and height).

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You may include more info/screenshot of the intended outcome or the issue. I'm not quite sure what do you mean by identical extent in this case, but I think align rasters tool could do this. The tool allow you to both align and resample rasters as well as set crs. the outputs are new versions of each dataset

Comment: I added addictional screenshot and explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, all raster images should be on top of each other?

For this, you can use the tool translate from gdal. To use it in QGIS, you can look for the tool "Translate (convert format)" and then add under "Additional command-line parameters" the parameter:

```
-a_ullr  <upper left x> <upper left y> <lower right x> <lower right y>
```

https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-a_ullr

With this solution, you have to do this for each layer separately, or you write a script for it and run it from the command line.

Comment: I tried it in normal QGIS and it didn't work. I opened QGIS with GRASS and it was running, but the values are still the same as previously, it didn't change at all.
I wanted to change it for NMT extent values so I added:
 -a_ullr  <606158.3214000000152737> <475781.3973000000114553> <651958.3214000000152737> <431681.3973000000114553>
maybe I can do it differently in ArcGIS?

Comment: You have to delete the Less and Greater Than Symbols and then it should work

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much. Can I somehow give you a positive feedback?

Comment: You're welcome. You could mark the answer as "accepted", then it is also clear for other users that the solution worked for you.